# Given ShortString is deprecated, what is the best method for limiting string length

Tags: string, delphi, field

It's not uncommon to have a record like this:

```
TAddress = record
  Address: string[50];
  City   : string[20];
  State  : string[2];
  ZIP    : string[5];
end;
```

Where it was nice to have hard-coded string sizes to ensure that the size of the string wouldn't exceed the database field size allotted for the data.

Given, however, that the `ShortString` type has been deprecated, what are Delphi developers doing to "solve" this problem?  Declaring the record fields as `string` gets the job done, but doesn't protect the data from exceeding the proper length.

What is the best solution here?

Comment: Nick, what problem are you trying to solve?  Do you want strings to be automatically truncated to a particular length when they have a longer string assigned to them?

Comment: Robert -- I guess I'm just a little nervous changing the declaration to string from string[xx].  I'm migrating a Delphi 7 app, and don't want to miss anything.  I'll be keeping an eye on the checking obviously, but it's pretty complex right now to ferret out if error checking and length-checking are needed.  If there is a more generally accepted solution, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: What happens when you push a longer string to the DB. Does something in the framework truncate it?

Comment: I pass every data container (especially edited by user) through a validator (visitor pattern), not only to check length. So i don't cut off any input data from user, but returning very clear information, why data could not be saved.

Comment: CustomAttributes may help you in your case

Comment: what about a simple array of char?

Comment: @Remko: Exactly what I have been saying all the time. Requires a little extra code, or a few functions to be written, but otherwise, it should not make a big difference.

Answer (score 5):

If I had to keep data from exceeding the right length, I'd let the database code handle it as much as possible.  Put size limits on the fields, and display data to the user in data-bound controls.  A `TDBEdit` bound to a string field will enforce the length limit correctly.  Set it up so the record gets populated directly from the dataset, and it will always have the right length.

Then all you need to worry about is data coming into the record from some outside source that is not part of your UI.  For that, use the same process.  Have the import code insert the data into the dataset, and let its length constraints do the validation for you.  If it raises an exception, reject the import.  If not, then you've got a valid dataset row that you can use to populate a record from.

Answer (score 5):

The short string types in your question don't really protect the strings from exceeding the proper length. When you assign a longer value to these short strings, the value is silently truncated.

I'm not sure what database access method you are using but I rather imagine that it will do the same thing. Namely truncate any over-length strings to the maximum length. In which case there is nothing to do.

If your database access method throws an error when you give it an over long string then you would need to truncate before passing the value to the database.

If you have to truncate explicitly, then there are lots of places where you might choose to do so. My philosophy would be to truncate at the last possible moment. That's the point at which you are subject to the limit. Truncating anywhere else seems wrong. It means that a database limitation is spreading to parts of the code that are not obviously related to the database.

Of course, all this is based on the assumption that you want to carry on silently truncating. If you want to do provide user feedback in the event of truncation, then you will need to decide just where are the right points to action that feedback.

Comment: If the string is user-entered then you need to provide truncation info at the earliest opportunity, I.e. in the UI. Doing it anywhere else will only expose user to cryptic developper messages or data loss.

Comment: @Eric that makes sense. It's clearly not what's happening with the short string code in the Q.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, my answer should be "do not mix layers".

I suspect that the string length is specified at the database layer level (a column width), or at the business application layer (e.g. to validate a card number).

From the "pure Delphi code" point of view, you should not know that your `string` variable has a maximum length, unless you reach the persistence layer or even the business layer.

Using attributes could be an idea. But it may "pollute" the source code for the very same reason that it is mixing layers.

So what I recommend is to use a dedicated Data Modeling, in which you specify your data expectations. Then, at the Delphi `var` level, you just define a plain `string`. This is exactly how our *mORMot* framework [implements data filtering and validation](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/06/01/Business-rules%3A-validate-and-filter-data): at Model level, with some dedicated classes - convenient, extendable and clean.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just porting from Delphi 7 to XE3, leave it be.  Also, although "ShortString" may be deprecated, I'll eat my hat if they ever remove it completely, because there are a lot of bits of code that will never be able to be rebuilt without it. ShortString + Records is still the only practical way to specify a byte-oriented file-of-record data storage.  Delphi will NEVER remove ShortString nor change its behaviour, it would be devastating to existing delphi code.  So if you really must define records and limit their length, and you really don't want those records to support Unicode, then there is zero reason to stop using or stop writing ShortString code.  That being said, I detest short-strings, and File-of-record, wish they would go away, and am glad they are marked deprecated.

That being said, I agree with mason and David entirely; I would say, Length checking, and validation are presentation/validation concerns, and Delphi's strong typing is NOT the right place or the right way to deal with them. If you need to put validation constraints on your classes, write helper classes that implement constraint-storage (EmployeeName is a string field and EmployeeName has the following length limit). In Edit controls for example, this is already a property.  It seems to me that mapping DB Fields to visual fields, using the new Binding system would be much preferable to trying to express constraints statically in the code.

User input validation and storage are different and length limits should be set in your GUI controls not in your data structures.

You could for example use Array of UnicodeChar, if you wanted to have a Unicode wide but length limited string.  You could even write your own LimitedString class using the new class helper methods in Delphi. But such approaches are not a maintainable and stable design.

If your SQL database has a field declared with `VARCHAR(100)` type, and you want to limit your user's input to 100 characters, you should do so at the GUI layer and forget about imposing truncation (data corruption, in fact) silently behind the scenes.

Comment: Of course it is possible to change code to do without it. It might require some thought, indeed, but is is certainly not impossible.

Comment: Breaking changes aren't that uncommon with NEXTGEN and double byte strings becoming standard these days. I built a carreer on fixing old serialization/deserialization code.

Comment: NEXTGEN is a pile of crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem - severely - upgrading from Delphi 6 to 2009 for what one program was/is doing it was imperative to be able to treat the old ASCII strings as individual ASCII characters.

The program outputs ASCII files (NO ANSI even) and has concepts such as over-punch on the last numeric digit to indicate negative. So the file format goes back a bit one could say!

After the first build in 2009 (10 year old code, well, you do don't you!) after sorting unit names etc there were literally hundreds of reported errors/ illegal assignments and data loss / conversion warnings...

No matter how good Delphi's back-room manipulation/magic with strings and chars I did not trust it enough.  In the end to make sure everything was back as it was I re-declared them all as array of byte and then changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Seems like wasted effort. Shortstring and string[3] (which is in effect ShortString with length limit 3) work the same in XE3 as they did in Delphi 6, so your port was clearly possible without changing their types. You chose one way (but not the easiest or best) way to resolve your compile errors. I feel your pain, but I think you might have gone the Long Way Round.  There are some implicit conversion warnings that you can fix by adding casts, or you can leave, but there is nothing seriously wrong that you can't fix with a few careful type declarations.

Comment: It didn't actually take that much effort. It was as much to do with the way I wrote it 10 years ago - they probably should have been arrays in the first place but the shortstring[n] was easy cheat. The whole manipulation focuses on a few routines called "MoveChars, MovecharsAndFill, etc. and heavy use of FillChar for initialisation. So more horses for courses :)

Comment: If your app was very small, great.  I have a 900K line app that would take about a year to hack Shortstring out of it, and in the end, if you didn't at least get it up to unicode, there would be no point in the removal of the shortstring other than as an incremental move.

Comment: As I said it cannot be moved to unicode or anything like it - it is what it is - The Text-file (ASCII) output MUST be exactly as specified. Can you imagine doing "Over Punch" in unicode? This is a concept brought forward from punched cards as it's name would suggest. Punched-card-unicode LOL:
 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_overpunch

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the delphi version, here's what works for me in delphi 2010:

**Version1**:

```
TTestRecordProp = record
private
  FField20: string;
  ...
  FFieldN: string
  procedure SetField20(const Value: string);
public
  property Field20: string read FField20 write SetField20;
  ...
  property FieldN: string ...
end;
...
procedure TTestRecordProp.SetField20(const Value: string);
begin
  if Length(Value) > 20 then
    /// maybe raise an exception?
    FField20 := Copy(FField20, 1, 20)
  else
    FField20 := Value;
end;
```

**Version2**:

```
TTestRecordEnsureLengths = record
  Field20: string;
  procedure EnsureLengths;
end;
...
procedure TTestRecordEnsureLengths.EnsureLengths;
begin
  // for each string field, test it's length and truncate or raise exception
  if Length(Field20) > 20 then
    Field20 := Copy(Field20, 1, 20); // or raise exception...
end;
```

// You have to call .EnsureLength before push data to db...

Personally, I'd recommend replacing records with objects, then you can do more tricks.